# Why is my second div in my container not showing?

Tags: html, css

I've taken CSS, HTML, and javascript code from https://codepen.io/supah/pen/zZaPeE to input a slideshow underneath my navigation bar. I now want to add an embed map using an iframe under the slideshow to be the third item on my webpage scrolling down, but it's appearing underneath the slideshow in a way where it's clipped off at the top. As a new coder, I believe the problem is the position: absolute, but I don't know if that's right or how to fix it. I've tried to use bottom, but it only moves the slideshow up and obscures the navbar. I've also tried out placing the iframe before the slideshow, and what happens is is that the slideshow moves down, but also clips.

My code for the HTML is largely the same as the codepen, except with pictures and text replaced. Because the iframe also works, I don't believe that the HTML is the issue.

```
   body,
    html {
      background: #110101;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .split-slideshow {
      display: block;
    }

    .slideshow {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      padding-top: 40px;
      left: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .slideshow .slider {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vw;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    .slideshow .slider * {
      outline: none;
    }

    .slideshow .slider .item {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      border: none;
    }
    .slideshow .slider .item .text {
      display: none;
    }
    .slideshow .slider .item img {
      min-width: 101%;
      min-height: 101%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    .slideshow .slick-dots {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 100;
      width: 40px;
      height: auto;
      bottom: auto;
      top: 50%;
      right: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
              transform: translateY(-50%);
      left: auto;
      color: #fff;
      display: block;
    }
    .slideshow .slick-dots li {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    .slideshow .slick-dots li button {
      position: relative;
      width: 20px;
      height: 15px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .slideshow .slick-dots li button:before {
      content: '';
      background: #fff;
      color: #fff;
      height: 2px;
      width: 20px;
      border-radius: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 0;
      left: auto;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
              transform: translateY(-50%);
      -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
      transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
      opacity: 0.6;
    }
    .slideshow .slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
      width: 40px;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .slideshow.slideshow-right {
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 50vw;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    .slideshow.slideshow-right .slider {
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
    }

    .slideshow-text {
      position: absolute;
      top: 56%;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      z-index: 100;
      font-size: 80px;
      width: 100vw;
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 100;
      pointer-events: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 20px;
      line-height: 1.5;
    }
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      .slideshow-text {
        font-size: 40px;
      }
    }

    .ss{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      border: white 2px solid;
    }
```

Sorry for the long excerpt of code, I just don't really know what exactly is the problem or if there are multiple issues occurring at once. I've taken out CSS code from the excerpt that even I know most likely is not the culprit.

EDIT: the HTML:

```
    <body>
      <div class="split-slideshow">
        <div class="slideshow">
          <div class="slider">
            <div class="item">
              <img src="img/ban1.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="img/ban2.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="img/ban3.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="img/ban4.png" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow-text">
          <div class="item"><a href="#" class="ss">TEXT ONE</a></div>
          <div class="item"><a href="#" class="ss">TEXT TWO</a></div>
          <div class="item"><a href="#" class="ss">TEXT THREE</a></div>
          <div class="item"><a href="#" class="ss">TEXT FOUR</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.12/jquery.mousewheel.js'></script>
      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js'></script>
      <script src="js/splitslick/js/index.js"></script>

      <div class="map">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3520.2685758805533!2d-82.46569269999999!3d28.0773494!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x88c2c74f729035a1%3A0xddc564fe471ed4fa!2s14304%20Capitol%20Dr%2C%20Tampa%2C%20FL%2033613!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1569802270070!5m2!1sen!2sus"
          width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Another edit: a snippet! The demo here actually runs a bit differently than what my computer interprets, but since the point that the iframe can't be seen stands, it's not a big deal at all.

```js
var $slider = $('.slideshow .slider'),
  maxItems = $('.item', $slider).length,
  dragging = false,
  tracking,
  rightTracking;

$sliderRight = $('.slideshow').clone().addClass('slideshow-right').appendTo($('.split-slideshow'));

rightItems = $('.item', $sliderRight).toArray();
reverseItems = rightItems.reverse();
$('.slider', $sliderRight).html('');
for (i = 0; i < maxItems; i++) {
  $(reverseItems[i]).appendTo($('.slider', $sliderRight));
}

$slider.addClass('slideshow-left');
$('.slideshow-left').slick({
  vertical: true,
  verticalSwiping: true,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  dots: true,
  speed: 1000,
  cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)'
}).on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

  if (currentSlide > nextSlide && nextSlide == 0 && currentSlide == maxItems - 1) {
    $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', -1);
    $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems);
  } else if (currentSlide < nextSlide && currentSlide == 0 && nextSlide == maxItems - 1) {
    $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems);
    $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', -1);
  } else {
    $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems - 1 - nextSlide);
    $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', nextSlide);
  }
}).on("mousewheel", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.deltaX > 0 || event.deltaY < 0) {
    $(this).slick('slickNext');
  } else if (event.deltaX < 0 || event.deltaY > 0) {
    $(this).slick('slickPrev');
  };
}).on('mousedown touchstart', function(){
  dragging = true;
  tracking = $('.slick-track', $slider).css('transform');
  tracking = parseInt(tracking.split(',')[5]);
  rightTracking = $('.slideshow-right .slick-track').css('transform');
  rightTracking = parseInt(rightTracking.split(',')[5]);
}).on('mousemove touchmove', function(){
  if (dragging) {
    newTracking = $('.slideshow-left .slick-track').css('transform');
    newTracking = parseInt(newTracking.split(',')[5]);
    diffTracking = newTracking - tracking;
    $('.slideshow-right .slick-track').css({'transform': 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, ' + (rightTracking - diffTracking) + ')'});
  }
}).on('mouseleave touchend mouseup', function(){
  dragging = false;
});

$('.slideshow-right .slider').slick({
  swipe: false,
  vertical: true,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 950,
  cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)',
  initialSlide: maxItems - 1
});
$('.slideshow-text').slick({
  swipe: false,
  vertical: true,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 900,
  cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)'
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  background: #110101;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.split-slideshow {
  display: block;
}

.slideshow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slideshow .slider {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
  z-index: 2;
}
.slideshow .slider * {
  outline: none;
}

.slideshow .slider .item {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
}
.slideshow .slider .item .text {
  display: none;
}
.slideshow .slider .item img {
  min-width: 101%;
  min-height: 101%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.slideshow .slick-dots {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 40px;
  height: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: auto;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}
.slideshow .slick-dots li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.slideshow .slick-dots li button {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
.slideshow .slick-dots li button:before {
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.slideshow .slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
  width: 40px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.slideshow.slideshow-right {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 50vw;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.slideshow.slideshow-right .slider {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.slideshow-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 56%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 80px;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .slideshow-text {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}

.ss{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border: white 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="split-slideshow">
    <div class="slideshow">
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fw800/background/20190222/ourmid/pngtree-blue-gradient-pattern-overlay-background-banner-image_50591.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fw800/background/20190222/ourmid/pngtree-blue-gradient-pattern-overlay-background-banner-image_50591.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fw800/background/20190222/ourmid/pngtree-blue-gradient-pattern-overlay-background-banner-image_50591.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fw800/background/20190222/ourmid/pngtree-blue-gradient-pattern-overlay-background-banner-image_50591.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-text">
      <div class="item"><a href="#" class="ss">TEXT ONE</a></div>
      <div class="item"><a href="#" class="ss">TEXT TWO</a></div>
      <div class="item"><a href="#" class="ss">TEXT THREE</a></div>
      <div class="item"><a href="#" class="ss">TEXT FOUR</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.12/jquery.mousewheel.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js'></script>
  <script src="js/splitslick/js/index.js"></script>

  <div class="map">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3520.2685758805533!2d-82.46569269999999!3d28.0773494!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x88c2c74f729035a1%3A0xddc564fe471ed4fa!2s14304%20Capitol%20Dr%2C%20Tampa%2C%20FL%2033613!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1569802270070!5m2!1sen!2sus"
      width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Show us the html code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Whilst I respect your assertion that your CSS code is not pertinent to the problem I think it would be wise to allow SO contributors to see it anyway _ Don't be too worried about the length of the code blocks in your question

Comment: Hello there, could you maybe use the snippet tool to post your code as a working demo? From my experience it's possible it's a position absolute, a float... There are many ways in which such a problem may happen.

Comment: @Adriano Here it is!

Comment: @GabrielFonseca I've added it!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was having problems getting used to the question format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understood you seem to want something close to the diagram bellow:

[image: image showing navbar, slideshow and map in this order]

If it is so, i think this may help you:

```js
var $slider = $('.slideshow .slider'),
  maxItems = $('.item', $slider).length,
  dragging = false,
  tracking,
  rightTracking;

$sliderRight = $('.slideshow').clone().addClass('slideshow-right').appendTo($('.split-slideshow'));

rightItems = $('.item', $sliderRight).toArray();
reverseItems = rightItems.reverse();
$('.slider', $sliderRight).html('');
for (i = 0; i < maxItems; i++) {
  $(reverseItems[i]).appendTo($('.slider', $sliderRight));
}

$slider.addClass('slideshow-left');
$('.slideshow-left').slick({
  vertical: true,
  verticalSwiping: true,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  dots: true,
  speed: 1000,
  cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)'
}).on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

  if (currentSlide > nextSlide && nextSlide == 0 && currentSlide == maxItems - 1) {
    $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', -1);
    $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems);
  } else if (currentSlide < nextSlide && currentSlide == 0 && nextSlide == maxItems - 1) {
    $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems);
    $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', -1);
  } else {
    $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems - 1 - nextSlide);
    $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', nextSlide);
  }
}).on("mousewheel", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.deltaX > 0 || event.deltaY < 0) {
    $(this).slick('slickNext');
  } else if (event.deltaX < 0 || event.deltaY > 0) {
    $(this).slick('slickPrev');
  };
}).on('mousedown touchstart', function(){
  dragging = true;
  tracking = $('.slick-track', $slider).css('transform');
  tracking = parseInt(tracking.split(',')[5]);
  rightTracking = $('.slideshow-right .slick-track').css('transform');
  rightTracking = parseInt(rightTracking.split(',')[5]);
}).on('mousemove touchmove', function(){
  if (dragging) {
    newTracking = $('.slideshow-left .slick-track').css('transform');
    newTracking = parseInt(newTracking.split(',')[5]);
    diffTracking = newTracking - tracking;
    $('.slideshow-right .slick-track').css({'transform': 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, ' + (rightTracking - diffTracking) + ')'});
  }
}).on('mouseleave touchend mouseup', function(){
  dragging = false;
});

$('.slideshow-right .slider').slick({
  swipe: false,
  vertical: true,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 950,
  cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)',
  initialSlide: maxItems - 1
});
$('.slideshow-text').slick({
  swipe: false,
  vertical: true,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 900,
  cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)'
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  background: #110101;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.split-slideshow {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.slideshow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 70vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slideshow .slider {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 70vw;
  z-index: 2;
}
.slideshow .slider * {
  outline: none;
}

.slideshow .slider .item {
  height: 70vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
}
.slideshow .slider .item .text {
  display: none;
}
.slideshow .slider .item img {
  min-width: 101%;
  min-height: 101%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.slideshow .slick-dots {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 40px;
  height: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: auto;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}
.slideshow .slick-dots li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.slideshow .slick-dots li button {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
.slideshow .slick-dots li button:before {
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.slideshow .slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
  width: 40px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.slideshow.slideshow-right {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 50vw;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
}
.slideshow.slideshow-right .slider {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.slideshow-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 56%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 80px;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .slideshow-text {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}

.ss{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border: white 2px solid;
}

.map {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 20vh;
}

.navbar {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 10vh;
   background: #888;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar"></div>
  <div class="split-slideshow">
    <div class="slideshow">
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fw800/background/20190222/ourmid/pngtree-blue-gradient-pattern-overlay-background-banner-image_50591.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fw800/background/20190222/ourmid/pngtree-blue-gradient-pattern-overlay-background-banner-image_50591.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fw800/background/20190222/ourmid/pngtree-blue-gradient-pattern-overlay-background-banner-image_50591.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fw800/background/20190222/ourmid/pngtree-blue-gradient-pattern-overlay-background-banner-image_50591.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-text">
      <div class="item"><a href="#" class="ss">TEXT ONE</a></div>
      <div class="item"><a href="#" class="ss">TEXT TWO</a></div>
      <div class="item"><a href="#" class="ss">TEXT THREE</a></div>
      <div class="item"><a href="#" class="ss">TEXT FOUR</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.12/jquery.mousewheel.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js'></script>
  <script src="js/splitslick/js/index.js"></script>

  <div class="map">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3520.2685758805533!2d-82.46569269999999!3d28.0773494!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x88c2c74f729035a1%3A0xddc564fe471ed4fa!2s14304%20Capitol%20Dr%2C%20Tampa%2C%20FL%2033613!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1569802270070!5m2!1sen!2sus"
      width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place map on top

```
.map {
   position : absolute;
   z-index  : 100;
   bottom   : 10px;
}
```

If you want it to appear on page 3...

```
     <div class="slider">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/ban1.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/ban2.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/ban3.png" />

          // Put your map div here

        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/ban4.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
```

This works using the codepen you supplied.